# Dynamically set a hyperlink control's NavigateUrl property inline

Tags: asp.net, .net, hyperlink, webforms

How can I dynamically set a stand alone(not in gridview) hyperlink control's NavigateUrl property inline in the aspx page?

I have tried to do the following, but it did not work.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="MyLink"
  NavigateUrl="../mypage.aspx?id=<%= pageid %>"
  runat="server">My Page</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could do this in the codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string pageid = "123";
        MyLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("../mypage.aspx?id={0}", pageid);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that @Marko Ivanovski pointed me in the comments that this hyperlink is inside a `GridView` which I didn't notice in the beginning the easiest would be to use databinding (`<%#` syntax):

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink 
            id="MyLink" 
            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("pageid", "~/mypage.aspx?id={0}")  %>'
            runat="server">
        My Page
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

In this case `pageid` is a property of the data source.

---

UPDATE 2:

Do you really need a server side control? How about:

```
<a href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/mypage.aspx?id=" + pageid) %>">
    My Page
</a>
```

Comment: He mentions that the link is inside a GridView :)

Comment: @Marko, right, thanks for pointing this out. I didn't read the question carefully :-)

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.  I actually did want to find out how to do it outside a DataGrid/GridView.  I'm using just a normal hyperlink.  I updated the question to clarify.  Also I'm looking for how to do it inline as opposed to using the .NavigateUrl property from codebehind.

Comment: @metanito, this can't be done in the circumstances you describe. I would recommend you codebehind or simple HTML (I know that WebForms could have side effects to people using them too much - you simply forget the basics of how the web works).

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I thought about using just a normal <a> tag but I also want to set other properties of the link in code behind.  Also, yes, using webforms for 10 years I've forgotten html :(

Answer (score 4):

You can actually write a simple string method in your codebehind file.

**Example**

```
public string formatUrl(string pageId) {
    return "../mypage.aspx?id=" + pageId;
}
```

And then use it like..

```
<asp:HyperLink id="MyLink" NavigateUrl="<%= formatUrl(pageid) %>" runat="server">My Page</asp:HyperLink>
```

provided pageid exists

Comment: This is something I tried, but the code doesn't get run and it comes out as:
http://localhost/MySite/<%= formatUrl(pageid) %>

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="100">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="f.aspx?id=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.i")%>">
            <asp:Label ID="lblN" Font-Underline="true" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"n")%>' />
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```