# How to update NavigateUrl in asp:menu dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have 2 aspx page in the project and a menu is used to navigate between pages. It was working fine until I did some needed change to the project, and now the pages will only work if the URL has the additional string query "?UserId=XXX". The UserId is available in both the URL and a label lblUserID on the page.

Below is my menu items

```
<asp:MenuItem Text="Send Fax" NavigateUrl="SendFax.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Fax Status" NavigateUrl="FaxStatus.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
```

How can I achieve my goal? through javascript or codebehind?
Please give me some hint, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the following post [Dynamically set Hyperlink......](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594143/dynamically-set-hyperlink-controls-navigateurl-property-inline)
I was able to update the NavigateUrl through codebehind running the simple function that loop through the menu items

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{  updateMenuItems();

.........

private void updateMenuItems()
{
    string UserId = "?UserId=" + lblUserID.Text;

    foreach (MenuItem i in Menu1.Items)
    {
        i.NavigateUrl = i.NavigateUrl + UserId;
    }
}
```