# Reference to querystring parameters in .aspx markup code

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to reference a query string parameter inside an `HyperLink` element :

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval(Request["id"], "~/PATH/Page.aspx?id={0}") %>'  Text="reload" />
```

I tought it was simple... but it's not: `NavigateUrl` property probably fails evaluation an the resulting url is empty.
Of course `Request["id"]` is valid at the time the page is evaluated.

I tried also using `string.format()` instead `Eval()` with the same result.

Comment: To verify did you step through and debug your code do you see a value returned for the ID using either Eval or string.format?  Its been quite a while, but I remember having to use Request["id"].QueryString  (or similar format) so the code knows if its a request from query string or from request.form submit.

Comment: yes. As I wrote Request["id"] is not NULL and return an integer value when the page loads

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594143/dynamically-set-a-hyperlink-controls-navigateurl-property-inline

Comment: yes ... it doesn't work.. the url stay empty...

Comment: it looks like the code do not run at all.. if I put a tracepoint on the inline code I can evaluate the Request["id"] call but if I change the call with a public method defined in codebehind this's never called.

Answer (score 1):

> This means <%# ... %> data-binding expression
> The data-binding expression creates binding between a server control property and a data source when the control's DataBind method of this server control is called on the page.

But you are only formatting a string to set for your NavigateUrl

> Inline code block is not allowed to any server tag controls
> those that have runat="server"

You can only set it via code either eg: inside the Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/PATH/Page.aspx?id={0}", Request["id"]);
}
```

Your second post work's because it's a pure html client control and not a server control.

Source: [Inline Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/inline-expressions)

Comment: I prefer an `.aspx` inline solution istead a codebehind approach in this case. But I really appreciated your explanation. This dissipate doubts I got on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what the problem was but the following code works:

```
<a href="~/PATH/Page.aspx?id=<%= Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() %>" >reload</a>
```

I tried several times including one using `<a></a>` tag with `runat="server"` property (not working).